# Exception de-serializing SOAP XML into Object

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, xml-deserialization

I am developing a WCF Service that can accept and return SOAP 1.1 messages.  However, I am having problems deserializing the SOAP body to my object.  At the moment I have;

```
namespace MyAPI
{    
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]     
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",           
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        Message ProcessMessgae(Message message);       
    }
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{  
    public Message ProcessMessgae(Message message)
    {
        MessageBuffer buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(8192);

        // Get a copy of the original message.
        Message msgCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();

        // Take another copy of the same message. 
        Message returnMsg = buffer.CreateMessage();

        // Use the msgCopy to get an XML and extract the body contents. Once this message has been read and consumed,

        System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader xrdr = msgCopy.GetReaderAtBodyContents();

        string bodyData = xrdr.ReadOuterXml();

        var reader = new StringReader(bodyData);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OTA_HotelAvailRQ));
        var instance = (OTA_HotelAvailRQ)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        return returnMsg; 
    }
}
```

This is my auto-generated object

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2046.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")]
public partial class OTA_HotelAvailRQ : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string echoTokenField;

    private System.DateTime timeStampField;

    private bool timeStampFieldSpecified;

    private bool targetFieldSpecified;

    private decimal versionField;

    private bool availRatesOnlyField;

    private bool availRatesOnlyFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string EchoToken
    {
        get
        {
            return this.echoTokenField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.echoTokenField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("EchoToken");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime TimeStamp
    {
        get
        {
            return this.timeStampField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.timeStampField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TimeStamp");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool TimeStampSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.timeStampFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.timeStampFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TimeStampSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Version
    {
        get
        {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.versionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Version");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool AvailRatesOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return this.availRatesOnlyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.availRatesOnlyField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("AvailRatesOnly");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool AvailRatesOnlySpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.availRatesOnlyFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.availRatesOnlyFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("AvailRatesOnlySpecified");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code I'm getting an exception on the following line `var instance = (OTA_HotelAvailRQ)serializer.Deserialize(reader);`

The SOAP XML I'm posting is;

`<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">thebest</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <OTA_HotelAvailRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Version="1.0" TimeStamp="2005-08-01T09:30:47+02:00" EchoToken="fb57388d" AvailRatesOnly="true">
</OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

The actual exception is;[image]

Comment: does `var instance = msgCopy.GetBody<OTA_HotelAvailRQ>()` work any better?

Comment: I tried as you suggested above but get '{"Expecting element 'OTA_HotelAvailRQ' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyAPI'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'OTA_HotelAvailRQ', namespace 'http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05'. "}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you add your namespace to the xmlserializer?

```
var instance = (OTA_HotelAvailRQ)serializer.Deserialize(reader, "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05");
```

Another option would be do something like the below, you may have to ReadOuterXml() instead of ReadInnerXml, the namespace may be able to be removed from this method too:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XElement body = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(msgCopy.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadInnerXml());
var instance = Deserialize<OTA_HotelAvailRQ>(body, "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05");

public static T Deserialize<T>(XElement xElement, string nameSpace)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xElement.ToString())))
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), nameSpace);
        return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

If you are still having problems, there is also a way using the `DataContractSerializer` or a `SoapreflectionImporter`, but you don't have a very complex object there those may be overkill.

Comment: Adding var instance = (OTA_HotelAvailRQ)serializer.Deserialize(reader, "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"), doesn't compile.

Comment: Your second suggestion worked, however like you mentioned I had to use ReadOuterXml() instead of ReadInnerXml()

Comment: @Tommassiov the part that did not compile, my mistake, the namespace has to be added to the constructor when you instantiate the xmlserialer, not on the deserialize method. Glad the second option work though :)